# How can I execute the method from a button-click from another class?

Tags: java, android, button

I have a Main-Activity and an AddItem-Activity in Android Studio.
I have a RecyclerView in my Main-Activity and in the second Activity (AddItem) I have formular to add items to the RecyclerView in the Main-Activity. What I also have is a button called "ADD" in the AddItem-Activity. 
The method, which will be executed, when the button is clicked is in the Main-Activity.

Is it possible to execute the code of the Click-Event-method in the Main-Class from the addItem-Class?

There is also a png, to show what I mean.

Thanks for help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W69Z4.png)

Comment: That function will not be static so no, you cannot call it from another activity. If you start the add item activity from the main activity then as long as the add item activity is in front Android can kill your main activity.

Comment: Check EventBus or Broadcast Receiver, it is used to communicate between two activities